# OpenCV Window Freezing when trying to combine with Neural Network Image Classification

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, pytorch

I am using a NN to detect 4 types of objects (chassis, front-spoiler, hubcap, wheel) in the live feed of my webcam. When one is detected, I want to display an image with information about it (chassis.png, front-spoiler.png, hubcap.png, wheel.png).
When I run my NN and hold one of the items in front of the webcam, the opencv windows freezes and doesnt display anything. What is the reason for that?

```
def displayImg(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.imshow("window", img)

# ----------------LIVE DETECTIONS ---------------
imagePath = "picture.jpg"
frontSpoilerImageOpen = False
chassisImageOpen = False
hubcapImageOpen = False
wheelImageOpen = False

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='yolov5/runs/train/exp5/weights/last.pt', force_reload=True)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    results = model(frame)

    try:
        detectedItem = results.pandas().xyxy[0].iloc[0, 6]
        if detectedItem == "front-spoiler" and not frontSpoilerImageOpen:

            frontSpoilerImageOpen = False
            chassisImageOpen = False
            hubcapImageOpen = False
            wheelImageOpen = False

            displayImg(os.path.join("imagesToDisplay", "front-spoiler.png"))
            frontSpoilerImageOpen = True

        elif detectedItem == "chassis" and not chassisImageOpen:

            frontSpoilerImageOpen = False
            chassisImageOpen = False
            hubcapImageOpen = False
            wheelImageOpen = False

            displayImg(os.path.join("imagesToDisplay", "chassis.png"))
            chassisImageOpen = True

        elif detectedItem == "hubcap" and not hubcapImageOpen:

            frontSpoilerImageOpen = False
            chassisImageOpen = False
            hubcapImageOpen = False
            wheelImageOpen = False

            displayImg(os.path.join("imagesToDisplay", "hubcap.png"))
            hubcapImageOpen = True


        elif detectedItem == "wheel" and not wheelImageOpen:

            frontSpoilerImageOpen = False
            chassisImageOpen = False
            hubcapImageOpen = False
            wheelImageOpen = False

            displayImg(os.path.join("imagesToDisplay", "wheel.png"))
            wheelImageOpen = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: please review [mre]. you could strip that code down by a lot while still reproducing the issue. that's always a good idea and part of good debugging practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains no `waitKey` at all.

OpenCV GUI (`imshow`) requires `waitKey` to work.

This is described in all OpenCV documentation and tutorials.

- one basic tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html
- documentation for `imshow` mentions the requirement: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563

`waitKey` isn't about delays or breaks. It runs the event loop that all GUI processing requires.

You can use `waitKey(1)` for the shortest non-zero delay of one millisecond (a little more in practice), or you can use `pollKey()`, which will not wait even that millisecond.

Comment: Thank you, I thought waitkey was for waiting until a key is pressed (like time.sleep but you have to press a key)

Comment: it is for that _too_. the naming is unfortunate, and ancient, probably over 20 years old, and impossible to change now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Adding cv2.waitKey after cv2.imshow helped in my case:

```
cv2.imshow("window", img)
cv2.waitKey(1)  # perform GUI housekeeping tasks
```